# Scaled density is messing with my fonts

Tags: android, fonts, screen

I have several devices (smartphones and tablets)... but some of them have the value "scaledDensity" set in 1.5 (You can get this value using the DisplayMetrics class). This is a nuisance because all the fonts in my app on that devices are being scaled up by 50%... (All my fonts use "sp"). In fact, all the fonts in the device are scaled up...

Well... the questions are:

Why a manufacturer would want to do that thing... ?

How can I set my fonts to use a scaled density of 1.0?

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html This is expected behavior. On high density devices, the fonts get larger to accomodate the same physical space as the smaller size would on a low or medium density device.

Comment: Why not use "dp" like Android suggests?