# HTC Desire X and Samsung Galaxy S Duos (GT-7582) - layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, htc-android

I have run into this strange issue. The two devices that I mentioned in the ques title have almost same specs in terms of screen sizes (if I am not missing something) as both are 4.0-inch hdpi phones (I think!?). However, one has got layouts coming up as close to shared .psd files (Samsung) as possible but, another (HTC) shows lot of differences like smaller font sizes but, larger padding. I tried different std. layout folders (small, large, xlarge) but, not to much help.

It would be great if somebody could throw some light on the issue.

TIA.

Best.

Edited: I am trying to know that even with the same spec(screen size and resolution) for both the devices, one device is showing expected layout as designed in eclipse while other is showing smaller font sizes, different padding etc. One question is why it is happening in first place despite using dp and sp. Secondly, what to do now? I mean how to know which layout folder could help as hit and try doesn't seem to work so far. Although I intend to invest more time on it today.

HTC Desire X (Display): http://www.htc.com/www/smartphones/htc-desire-x/#/
Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2 (Display): http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/duos/GT-S7582ZKAMID

Comment: Do they have the same font size in another app they both have, like settings?

Comment: No, they don't have same font size. In fact, after trying to find out some difference in the two devices, I found that they have different scaledDensity (Samsung 1.5 has while htc has 1.275) whereas density is the same i.e. 1.5 (hdpi)

Comment: Further, I think this is what http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106993/scaled-density-is-messing-with-my-fonts is probably happening and I am not really understanding what to do now.

Comment: scaledDensity is user editable. It defines the difference between dp and sp. And can be changed in settings -> Display -> font size. So maybe best to try to make the layout work with both.